# git clone gets wrong depot: command line does not override setting in global config

Tags: git, amazon-ec2, git-config

I have two repos living on an EC2 reserved instance.

I've successfully cloned each of them to various client platforms (Windows, Mac, Ubuntu) but when I tried to clone them on to a Windows instance on EC2 I kept getting just one of the repos even when I asked for the other one.

```
git clone ubuntu@gitServer:/git_repos/repoOne.git   // gives me repoOne
git clone ubuntu@gitServer:/git_repos/repoTwo.git   // also gives me repoOne!
```

After trying lots of the usual suspects (alias, different versions of git, verifying that I could access the repo using ssh directly), I stumbled upon the answer.

Somehow my git global config had gotten an entry for "remote.origin.url" that pointed to repoOne.  All well and good but I'm surprised that specifying the URL on the command line didn't override the config setting.

In Pro Git (page 11) it says "*Each level overrides values in the previous level*".  While not stated explicitly I thought options on the command line overrode everything?

I guess my actual question is: what are the rules for configuration resolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres a snipped from the git-scm book:

> You saw some simple Git configuration details in the first chapter, but I’ll go over them again quickly here. Git uses a series of configuration files to determine non-default behavior that you may want. The first place Git looks for these values is in an /etc/gitconfig file, which contains values for every user on the system and all of their repositories. If you pass the option --system to git config, it reads and writes from this file specifically.
>
> The next place Git looks is the ~/.gitconfig file, which is specific to each user. You can make Git read and write to this file by passing the --global option.
>
> Finally, Git looks for configuration values in the config file in the Git directory (.git/config) of whatever repository you’re currently using. These values are specific to that single repository. Each level overwrites values in the previous level, so values in .git/config trump those in /etc/gitconfig, for instance. You can also set these values by manually editing the file and inserting the correct syntax, but it’s generally easier to run the git config command.

More can be found at: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration

Im not sure the url on the command line is intended to specifically override the value you mentioned in the config file, which may be why you weren't seeing it overridden.  On the commandline git says you are passing it ...and I imagine that yes, that url does become remote.origin.url, eventually...but early in the clone process it wouldn't have fully configured the new remote (essentially), so the presiding config variable overrode the intended url.

That's my understanding and thought process at least.

Comment: Thanks!  That's as good as explanation as one could hope for.  Still seems like a bug to me as the user shouldn't have to know that level of detail of the implementation of the command.